# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:/User/A/model/saved_model.pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, oserror

Instead of accessing the model online, I downloaded a pre-trained EfficentNet model on my computer. My code works fine when I access the file online at:  "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet21k_b0/feature_vector/2" However, it doesn't work from my local machine; it throws this error message "OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:/User/A/model/saved_model.pb". Can someone please help?

```
input_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNEL)

effinet_feature_extractor_model = "C:/User/A/model/saved_model.pb"

pretrained_effinet_model_without_top_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    effinet_feature_extractor_model, input_shape=input_shape, trainable=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is there? What does `Path(effinet_feature_extractor_model).exists()`  return?

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot from your op system showing the folder where the file is?

Answer (score 0):

What about

`effinet_feature_extractor_model = r"C:\User\A\model\saved_model.pb"`

Comment: The first path is identical to the question. `/` isn't an escape character.

Comment: No, it is not. The first path has an additional r. That is the difference. It is correct, that / isnt an escape character. It might work for him/her adding the r and trying it with \ instead of /

Comment: I know what that `r` means. The resulting string is identical to the question, because all characters are handled as simple characters.

Comment: Ok, I see, then I change it and maybe the second version works, at least its worth giving it a try....

Comment: It's far more likely that the file is *not* where the OP things it is

Comment: True, but we cannot evaluate this from distance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `effinet_feature_extractor_model = "C:/User/A/model/saved_model.pb"`,
I used `effinet_feature_extractor_model = "C:/User/A/model/"` and the problem is solved!